# Calling a constructor from a different class python

Tags: python, constructor

In one python file titled overall model, I have defined a constructor. In the same folder as the first python file, I have another python file that calls the constructor.

File 1:

```
class OverallModel:

    __init__(self,file_name):

        #uses the file_name to do a series of calculations and then prints a result
```

File 2:

```
class Runner:

    x = OverallModel("file_name")
```

However. I am getting the message that OverallModel is an undefined name in file 2. Am I suppose to import file 1 or am I not properly calling the constructor? Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: both classes are called OverallModel?

Comment: You get the undefined name error because in file 2, while you are still defining `OverallModel`, you are trying to create an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

An import is indeed needed, and you also missed the def keyword in the constructor:

`file1.py`

```
class OverallModel:

    def __init__(self,file_name):
        print "hey"
```

`file2.py`

```
from file1 import OverallModel

x = OverallModel("file_name")
```

Result:

```
$ python file2.py
hey
```